# Component is not re render after state change in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

Here is the code . when it gets props for favList i console the output it show the change and in the `shouldComponentUpdate` also show the updated state but component is not re-render .
e.g if favlist update via `componentwillupdate` is 15 after get new props in `Componentwillrecieveprops` if gets 16 then i update the component state in shouldComponentUpdate it also show the 16 in next state but the its not re render
here is the code

```
class RestaurantList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  favRest:null,
  selectedRest: null,
  NearbyRestaurants: null,
  loading: true,
  favRest:this.props.favList
};

}
componentWillMount() {
this.setState({
  SnacksLoading: this.props.SnacksLoading,
  RestaurantLoading: this.props.RestLoading,
  fetchRestaurantsError: this.props.fetchRestaurantsError
})
if (this.props.favList) {
  this.setState({
    favRest: this.props.favList
  })
}
this.props.getNearbyrestaurants(50.8507855, 4.3539655);
this.props.getNearbySnacks(50.8507855, 4.3539655);
}


componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
console.log('[[[[[[[',next)
if (next.favList) {
    console.log('[[[[[[[',next.favList)
    this.setState({ favRest: next.favList });
    console.log('##########',this.state)
  }
if (next.Snacks) {
  this.setState({
    Snacks: next.Snacks,
    SnacksLoading: next.SnacksLoading,
    fetchSnacksError: next.fetchSnacksError
  });
}
if (next.Nearby) {
  this.setState({
    NearbyRestaurants: next.Nearby,
    RestaurantLoading: next.RestaurantLoading,
    fetchRestaurantsError: next.fetchRestaurantsError
  });
}
if (next.fetchRestaurantsError) {
  this.setState({ fetchRestaurantsError: next.fetchRestaurantsError })
}
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
console.log('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT',nextProps,nextState)
return true
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console.. can you also attach the complete next object in willReceive prop ?

Comment: no im not getting error in console .

Comment: Can you console.log next in willReceiveProps in and state in render and uptate the post

Comment: Please add the render() method as well

Comment: Please add the render